# I want run command in exec()

Tags: php, linux

I want run command in exec(), command is-

```
curl https://api.ccu.akamai.com/ccu/v2/queues/default -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"objects":["http://mydomain.com/as.png"]}' -u uname1:pass1
```

Comment: Why don't you use phps buildin `curl` extension instead? That would be ore efficient and simplifies payload and error handling.

Comment: I want to know what the actual question is... All I see here is a statement :S

Answer (score 0):

```
echo exec("curl https://api.ccu.akamai.com/ccu/v2/queues/default -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" -d '{\"objects\":[\"http://mydomain.com/as.png\"]}' -u uname1:pass1")
```